# Button Firing 2 Scripts instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I have a table which allows users to make a selection from a list of items and stores the selected ID in a hidden form input, and then a submit button which validates to make sure the hidden form input is not empty.

Here's the HTML showing a single row and the submit button:

```
<tr class="" id="PR7518">
  <td>1234A</td>
  <td>Option A</td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Select</button>
  </td>

  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="buttonType" value="saveSelected" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

The submit button is invoking both of the following scripts, when I only want it to invoke the form submit (2nd script):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success').click(function() {
    $('#productID').val(productID);
  });
});



$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#productID').val() == '') {
    $("#productID_Error").show();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Not sure what change I need to make to prevent the submit button from invoking the first script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `:not([type="submit"])` to your selector in the first script to exclude the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.btn-success:not([type="submit"])').click(function() {
    $('#productID').val(productID);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first selector `$('button.btn-success')` is selecting both of the buttons since they both have the class 'btn-success'. You need to add some sort of unique identifier to the first button so that you can select it without getting both buttons. You can do this by adding another class or id to the first button and then adjusting your selector to point to that unique identifier.